# What is screen's "Multi display mode"?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

`screen`'s man page mentions a "Multi display mode" at one place:

```
-x   Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display
    mode).
```

It's the only place where "Multi display mode" is mentioned.

What is it? Is understanding "Multi display mode" important for any other `screen`'s options or commands?

Comment: If i was to guess, i would say share a screen session with another user that is already attached to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `screen -x` allows you to connect to a session that it currently
attached, without forcing it to detach. For example, if you do this in
two separate xterms, you will see input and output of both instances
simultaneously. This is useful when logging in from several locations;
it avoids having to reattach once you go back to the location where you
first attached to screen.

To answer the "is it important?" part of your question, I would say
no; if you're just starting with screen, don't worry about it; the
feature will make sense if you ever fall into the scenario above, but
it's not a hard requirement either.